# Mapping Collection of generic objects nHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate-mapping, abstract-class

So, I'm stuck with this setup... a hypothetical would be a class with a roster of children, and there's two types of children: boy & girl

```
public class ClassRoster
{
public IList<Child> Children{get;set;}
}

public abstract class Child
{
public string Sex {get;}
}

pubic class Boy
: Child
{
public override string Sex { get { return "M"; } }
}

public class Girl
: Child
{
public override string Sex { get { return "F"; } }
}
```

(most likely, this is a bad example)... when I go to retrieve the list of children from the db, do I need to specify the discriminator value to the collection, or can nHibernate use the mapping I've done for Child/Boy/Girl already?

I'm asing because when I do this similarly for a project I'm working on, I'm getting a "WrongClassException" thrown from nHibernate.

---

I feel like this is not clear enough.  In my project, I've already got the mapping handled that I can call into the database, and pull a list of children out, and it maps the boys and girls as expected.  What I'm trying to do is to call the class roster, and get a list of children where the collection has all the boys and girls.

Comment: The bad is that you use string in bad way, insatead of that use enum type.

Comment: Ok... so it's realistically an enum in the "real" implementation.  I'm asking specifically when I map the generic "child" type, do I need to then tell the bag how to form a girl and how to form a boy, or am I approaching this all wrong?

Comment: The maping would be strongly apreciate. Because loading a bag should not cause any problem. As for resolving objects to it is responsible the disriminator for Child class

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is [NHibernate - Inheritance Mapping](http://knol.google.com/k/nhibernate-chapter-8-inheritance-mapping#)

Comment: I have that in already for the object.  What I'm trying to find out is if I have to define the inheritance mapping again for the collection or if it automatically uses the inheritance mapping from the actual object mapping hbm file.

Answer (score 0):

Wound up being something stupid.  There was a 3rd level I was not taking into account, and the mapping between the ClassRoster and the School was the issue... I has to do the one-to-one mapping to link up to "School" instead of "High School".

If I can generalize the code enough, I'll post it out here for further reference... honestly, it was a pebcak error.